# Slowing down object in Farseer

Tags: c#, xna, farseer

I'm using Farseer in XNA and using the function named ApplyLinearImpulse() to get an object to move in a specific direction.

How can I get the object to slow down naturally using Farseer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was achieved through the LinearDamping property.

Answer (score 1):

According to Mr. Newton objects retain their state until acted upon by an outside force. So if you want it to stop your going to have apply a force in the opposite direction or let friction do it for you. Since you say "naturally" I assume you want to apply friction.

Friction is applied when two objects collide as long as you set it via the Body.Friction property.

If you want friction against the background there is a joint called the Friction Joint which always applies friction to the body just like as if it was on a table sliding around.